# global variable access synchronization between two processes

Tags: c, linux

I have a global boolean variable that both parent and child process can write to. The child process is just forked (no exec() called).

In C/Linux, how do I go about synchronizing access to this global? In C/C++ threading world, I could have used a mutex.

Comment: And if you actually had a shared variable, then you could still use a mutex to synchronize access to it.  You'll need to ensure that it's a process-shared mutex, however.  The C11 standard library contains a mutex implementation that does not appear to have provisions to operate across processes, but that's new enough that comparatively little code uses it.  If you use pthreads' mutex implementation, on the other hand, it *does* have a provision for mutexes that are shared across processes.

Comment: OK. I am working with C++11 codebase, and yes the standard library mutex do not give protection across processes. I am going to create a shared memory segment in the parent process's thread - which is a cpp11 thread. I will have to see how I can synchronize this shared segment.

Answer (score 3):

After calling `fork`, each process has its own copy of any variables in use.  The global variable in the parent and the global in the child are completely distinct from each other, so they can't be used as a common variable.

If you want the two processes to share data, you would need to either create a pipe using the `pipe` function to pass data between the two, or you would need to create a shared memory segment that both processes would have access to.

Comment: thanks. I am actually currently using a pipe. But the problem is that the child process hangs on an external library call and hence cant reach the statement where it writes the boolean to true on pipe. The parent therefore blocks indefinitely on read(). The original goal is that parent, in another thread, keeps polling for this boolean value and if it does not get set to true (by child) for a certain duration, then the parent can kill and restart the process. I will explore the shared memory option.

Comment: @user2930006: Sounds like an XY problem. Why don't you use threads?

Comment: @Olaf I was using threads. So the child process that I have created was actually a thread. I am working on C++ and there is no safe way in the standard to kill a thread (which had hanged). Hence created a new process to do the same task as I will be able to control the child process from the parent.

Comment: @user2930006: If you are using C++, why is the question tagged C??

Comment: @user2930006, a process *has* one or more threads, but a thread is not itself a process.  This distinction turns out to be pretty important when it comes to synchronization issues.